# How to make .local resolve not via mDNS on Mac OS Mohave?

Tags: macos, dns, bonjour, mdns

My ISP provides useful service on .local domain which is absolutely necessary. 
But I can't ping it from my Mac PC. I found out that the "problem" connected to Bonjour service and all .local domains resolving via mDNS not DNS. How to make all .local domains could resolve via DNS first and only then via mDNS?
As I understand, I could add my xxx.local to somewhere as exception - this is the first way (describe it please, although it is not the best way as provider could change ip associated with this domain name and I should manually control it). And the second, preferable way, as described above - resolve .local via DNS first and only then via mDNS.
P.S. I've read answers to similar questions here but none of them helped.
P.P.S. As a temporary solution I've added ip address for `domain.local` to hosts file.

Answer (score 3):

If your domain is foo.local and you know the IP addresses of your nameservers then do the following:

1. Create a directory called /etc/resolver
2. Inside /etc/resolver create a file called foo.local
3. Then add your nameservers and IP addresses to foo.local

An example of foo.local:

nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX

nameserver YY.YY.YY.YY